# Order by enum value in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I normally would order a column in sqlalchemy by using `order_by(TableName.column_name.asc())`
, for example. One of my columns is a string enum and I want to order it by the value of the enum, which is different from the enum order.

How does one do this? I've tried `TableName.enum_column_name.value.asc()` but value doesn't exist there.

Edit:

Model definition:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):                                                          
    C = "C"                                                                  
    B = "B"                                                                
    A = "A"

class MyModel:
    my_field: MyEnum = Column(ENUM(MyEnum), index=True, nullable=False)
```

I am then trying in a query to order by the value of the enum alphabetically:

```
.order_by(MyModel.my_field.asc())
```

I am wondering how to order the values of the enum alphabetically rather than by the order in the enum?

Comment: Can you publish the definition of this model + field (specifically the field type)?

Comment: I added these to the question